# Getting a Compile Error: Sub or function not defined error in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am creating a sample VB6 application with CEF to embed a browser into the application. I used WebKitX control to achieve the same. Here is my sample code

```
Private Sub WebKitXCEF31_OnBrowserReady()

 WebKitXCEF31.ExecCommandSetFocus = True
 WebKitXCEF31.FormatUsingInternalSelectionAPI = True
 WebKitXCEF31.DownloadScripts = True
 WebKitXCEF31.Open "http://www.google.com/"

End Sub

Private Sub WebKitXCEF31_OnCreate(ByVal Settings As WebKitXCEF3Lib.ISettings, CommandLineSwitches As 
String)

 Settings.cache_path = App.Path + "\MyCache"
 Settings.application_cache = App.Path + "\MyAppCache"
 Settings.persist_session_cookies = 1
 Settings.persist_user_preferences = 1
 AddLog "CommandLineSwitches=" + CommandLineSwitches

End Sub

Private Sub WebKitXCEF31_OnLoadEnd()

 WebKitXCEF31.Preview
 WebKitXCEF31.Events = DOM_EVENT_SELECTSTART Or _
 DOM_EVENT_DOMSUBTREEMODIFIED Or _
 DOM_EVENT_DOMFOCUSIN Or _
 DOM_EVENT_CLICK Or _
 DOM_EVENT_EDITABLE_ELEMENT_CHANGED

End Sub
```

The `Form_Load` method is empty. When I run the application, an error is thrown at the OnCreate stub with the message '**Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined**.'. Is there any place specific where we need to define the stub/method before implementing it? I am new to VB6 and this is the first code that i have written. This code is available on WebKitX. Link : https://www.webkitx.com/webkitx.html

Comment: Is there an `AddLog()` method present in your project? Also, as a general rule of thumb in such cases: strip down the offending code to be as minimalistic as possible. In that case, I'd comment out all but the first line of code in `Sub WebKitXCEF31_OnCreate()` If that works, uncomment the next line etc. You'll eventually end up at the line that actually causes the error.

Comment: Agree, change `AddLog` to `Debug.Print` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step example of adding WebKitX to VB6 project is here:
https://www.webkitx.com/doc/light/Getting%20Started%20with%20Visual%20Basic%206.0.html